# Single-point-of-maintenance for Razor page parts that wrap model attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

My goal is to create many similar views that will differ only in the list of fields that they present. For example, many *Create* views for different models and different sets of fields. The following is a snippet from a scaffolded `Create.cshtml` page:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NameText, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NameText, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NameText, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NameDefinition, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NameDefinition, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NameDefinition, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class ="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NameComment, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NameComment, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NameComment, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

My understanding is that Partial Views can add above, below and among the `<div class="form-group"> . . . </div>` code blocks. But I am not aware of its capability to consume a reference to a model attribute (e.g., `NameText`) and then to wrap it with the code block.

Also my understanding is that the `@Helper` directive was removed from Razor (MVC 6) and it was not given any simple replacement.

I have already placed *both* the part of code that precede the above snippet *and* the part of code that follows it into a single partial view. With a little trick the two parts of code are merged around the above snippet, then everything is sent to the browser. But I need more than that. **How can I avoid also the repetition of code in the above snippet?**

What I would like to have:

- Many similar views that would differ only regarding to the list of fields
- Strong typing
- Single point of maintenance for the code that is common for many views

And as a side note: how should I had to search in order to find the answer myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A blog by Peter Vogel, [Building a Useful HTML Helper for ASP.NET MVC Views](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/10/01/building-a-useful-html-helper.aspx) provides just what I was looking for.